# Implementing Code Behind Clickable TextViews

Tags: android

I just started working with clickable TextViews in Eclipse.  The line in the code below:

```
t2.setOnClickListener(this); seems to be having a problem.
```

I have tried a variety of methods like setOnTouchListener etc. to handle the click events of a user clicking my TextViews but I am having trouble determining which method (if any) is appropriate behind clickable TextViews.

```
public class Soundboard extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.soundboard);

      TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
      t2.setFocusable(true);
      t2.setOnClickListener(this);

      t2.setOnClickListener(new View.setOnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View view) {
            mp.start();
          }
      });


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
t2.setOnClickListener(new View.setOnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View view) {
    mp.start();
  }
```

});

OR

```
TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
t2.setOnClickListener(this);

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == t2){
    // logic 
    }
}
```

This is the right way of setting on click listeners.

Answer (score 0):

In your code above, you are setting the `onClickListener` twice, which is unnecessary.  The second time you set it will override the first, and the result of the click should be the execution of `mp.start();`

Can you describe in more detail what your problem is?  What is or isn't happening when you run your app?